Windows 11 PC Keeps Logging Me Out After Locking (Win+L)
Recently, my Windows 11 PC has started logging me out every time I lock my machine (Win+L). I walk away from my PC and when I come back, any apps that I had running have closed, and all of my startup programs have to reload, etc.
I haven't changed anything with my power management settings. I have it set to never sleep or hibernate. The only thing that happens is my monitors shut off after a few minutes.
I can immediately tell that it's happened again when I walk into the room and see that my RGB fans have reverted to their default settings. I sign back in and everything has to load back up. Not sure what's going on here, but it is incredibly annoying. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Edit:
Another symptom that I've noticed is that I've got 2 different backgrounds for both of my monitors. After this happens, both monitors have the same background image.
Edit:
Upon even further inspection, I sat and waited for the computer to log out, and I found that the computer is actually completely rebooting. It powered off after about 15 minutes and started back up. This is really strange. Another thing I noticed is that I have a 5 bay external hard drive dock, and when the computer rebooted, the dock was still on, but not recognized by the computer. I had to shut it off and turn it back on for those disk drives to be available.

It's not happening immediately when I lock the PC. It is shortly after, though. I lock it, then come back about 20-30 minutes later and I've been logged out.

I have that set to "Never."

That's unchecked.

Check your Event Viewer for restart commands, or the report regarding whether the previous restart was expected or not. Follow these instructions: https://superuser.com/a/1498822/74026

This question is similar to: How do I identify the root cause of unexpected reboots?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I've figured out what my issue was. Using the powercfg /systempowerreport tool, I was able to use that report to determine that there were a lot of abnormal shut downs - likely from losing power unexpectedly. Looking at the event log, I found that there were a lot of Kernel-Power errors.
This brought my attention to my power strip. It wasn't tripping out, but I figured the most likely cause would be a large draw of current. If the voltage dropped, it might cause my PC to shut down in order to protect its circuits.
I've got an i9 with an RTX 4090 plugged into this power strip, along with my speakers, an external 5 bay hard drive enclosure, and 2 monitors. I removed the plug for my PC and plugged it directly into the wall, and all seems to have been resolved. Very strange that it only happened when the PC was locked though - not when it was using more power (e.g. while gaming).

it happen in windows 11 already automatically, try to click -Accounts, then -Sign-in options. Look for setting -Automatic log-off and see if it is set to "On." If this is the case, you can change the setting to "Off" to prevent your computer from automatically logging you out.

I don't see anything in account settings called "Automatic log-ff."

@wowhow - I checked every supported version of Windows and I wasn’t able to find this option. Can you provide additional detailed information?
